# c++: what is int[3] in sizeof(int[3])

Tags: c++

This is my example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int ar[][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    //cout << int[3]<<endl; // error C2062: type 'int' unexpected.
    cout << "sizeof(ar) / sizeof(int[3])  "<< sizeof(ar) / sizeof(int[3]) << endl;; 

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

It is from a book, though no explanation was given. What is int[3] here and why it works only as an argument of sizeof in this case?

Comment: People usually write that as `sizeof(ar) / sizeof(*ar)`

Comment: Or `sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0])` for the extra hint that you are working with an array.  Note, however, that this is unsafe, because if `ar` ends up being a pointer instead of an array, you get meaningless results.  C++11 provides `std::extent< decltype( ar ) >::value` for a compile-time length of array.

Comment: You write, "It is from a book". Well **BURN THAT BOOK**. The code is non-standard, non-portable, extremely awful.

Comment: By the way, which book is it? Just so that others can void it?

Comment: Presumably it's a book about writing for Windows using the Windows dialect of C++ (or, "C++-like language that is not C++" if you insist). On the same basis you should burn the GNU man page, since it describes GNU's C++ dialects (or "C++-like language that is not C++", if you insist).

Comment: @stevejessop: it is highly doubtful that your theory about the code being intended to illustrate the non-standard features employed, is correct. rather, it sounds argumentative. i hadn't expected that from you, so, learned something new today.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I didn't offer a theory what the code is intended to illustrate (I suspect it's intended to illustrate a use of `sizeof` to find the size of an array). I offered a theory about the book it appears in. If I'm arguing something, it's that book-burning is an over-reaction to non-standard variants of C++.

Comment: @SteveJessop: you go from argumentative to just evasive. jeez. but thanks for the lesson.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I guess I am a bit on Steve's side here. Whether such a book should be burnt or not depends greately on the title and how it is marketed. I would, for example, not complain about the GNU manpages, as they are clearly targeted for the GNU dialect, and if the book is called *Windows COM programming* then it delivers what it promises... I find the **BURN THAT BOOK** as a bit of an overreaction.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: the code is ungood even in Windows. but before the introduction of the layer for unicode in the year 2000, it was passable. perhaps the book is that old, but that is counter-indicated by the modern `<iostream>`. and it's not just the **needlessly non-standard** non-portable code. but also e.g. the `pause`, just very counter-productive practices. what you're doing by defending the teaching is to yourself teach the OP bad practices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int[3]` is a type declaration that represents an array of three integers.

Your commented code gives an error because you can't use a type as a variable.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(int[3])` is the size, in bytes, of an array of three integers. `sizeof` isn't an actual function that gets called while your program is running - it is resolved at compile time. `sizeof(ar) / sizeof(int[3])` will give you the number of rows in your array, since each row is 3 integers long (you declared it as `int ar[][3]`).

Answer (score 2):

The declaration

```
int ar[][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

is for an array of triplets of integers - it is a 2D array.

The sizeof expression

```
cout << "sizeof(ar) / sizeof(int[3])  "<< sizeof(ar) / sizeof(int[3]) << endl;
```

prints the number of *full* triplets that you get.  The last integer, 7, will not fall into any triplet.  You should see 2 printed.  `ar[0]` will contain `{1, 2, 3}` and `ar[1]` will contain `{4, 5, 6}`.